# How do I share char ** variable using shared memory

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory

I am using shared memory to communicate between two processes. I am using a char** to attach to the shared address space. The problem is that when I populate the data on the producer and then attach the consumer to the address space no data is transferred. I just get null values

This is a snippet of my producer

```
// create shared memory
shm_handle = shmget(key, BUFF_SIZE * PAGE_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
printf("\nhandle is %d\n", shm_handle);
// valid handle?
if (shm_handle == -1) {
  printf("shared memory creation failed\n");
  exit(0);
}
// attach to shared block, see man pages for detail
buf = (char**) shmat(shm_handle, 0, 0);
if (buf == (char **) -1) {
  printf("Shared memory attach failed");
  exit(0);
}
int a = 0;
buf = malloc(sizeof(char*) * BUFF_SIZE);
for (a = 0; a < BUFF_SIZE; a++) {
  buf[a] = malloc(sizeof(char) * PAGE_SIZE);
}
```

and the consumer

```
// create shared memory
shm_handle = shmget(key, BUFF_SIZE * PAGE_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
printf("handle is %d", shm_handle);
// valid handle?
if (shm_handle == -1) {
  printf("shared memory creation failed\n");
  exit(0);
}
char ** buft;
int a = 0;
// attach to shared block
buf = (char**) shmat(shm_handle, 0, 0);
if (buf == (char **) -1) {
  printf("Shared memory attach failed");
  exit(0);
}
buf = malloc(sizeof(char*) * BUFF_SIZE);
buft = malloc(sizeof(char*) * PAGE_SIZE);
for (a = 0; a < BUFF_SIZE; a++) {
  buf[a] = malloc(sizeof(char) * PAGE_SIZE);
  buft[a] = malloc(sizeof(char) * PAGE_SIZE);
}
printf("%s", buf[0]);
```

Comment: I don't think that's how you do it.  Isn't the malloc clobbering and overwriting your shared memory address?

Comment: `buf = (char**) shmat(...); buf = malloc(...);` you're throwing away what shmat gave you and replacing with a boring old non-shared allocation...

Comment: I put the malloc before attaching to the shared memory but it was still null

Comment: What Mat said!  Shared memory is generally just a pointer, not a whole thing you can malloc and free from, unless you want to write all those things yourself.

Comment: The shared memory is returned by shmat. malloc shall not be used at all in this case.

Comment: Do the consumer and producer have the same keys?  And should they both be creating?

Comment: @Marian If I don't use malloc, I cannot access my char** like a 2 dimensional array. I put stuff inside it as if it is a 2D array

Comment: @Jim Yes they both should be able to create so that either the consumer or producer could be started first. Could I have a pointer to (a pointer to a pointer) so that the shared memory would just be a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not putting your strings in shared memory. It's putting them on the heap, as `malloc` always does, because you are doing:

```
buf = (char**) shmat(shm_handle, 0, 0);
...
/* now throw away the value of `buf` you got from shm */
buf = malloc(sizeof(char*) * BUFF_SIZE);
```

What you will have to do is:

1. Not use the heap to allocate things you want in shared memory
2. Instead, grab a large enough amount of shared memory for everything, then copy it in, entry by entry - i.e. lay it out in memory manually.

Answer (score 1):

Allocating stuff in shared memory is tricky and error prone, as the addresses of the shared memory are not necessarily the same in every process.  Unless you take steps to ensure that addresses are the same, you can't store pointers in the shared memory as they won't point to the right place -- you need to instead store offsets into the shared memory.

Once you get the chunk of memory back from `shmat`, you need to manage allocations within that space yourself, keeping track of what is in use and what is free.  In the general case, you need to reimplement malloc/free using the shared space, as the system malloc/free always work with unshared heap memory.  This is non-trivial.

If you just want some working code that manages this, you can look [here](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/shm_malloc), but its not a simple problem.